# How to parallel the mechanism of SetDelayed as in ReplaceAll that makes substitution first, then possible further evaluation?

Tags: replacement, kernel

For `SetDelayed`, the kernel first makes the substitution literally, then does the further evaluation process if necessary.

[image]

I always think of `SetDelayed` and related functions as *global rule-replacing*, in contrary to the *local rule-replacing*, namely, `ReplaceAll`. However, such symmetry does not correspond so parallelly.

```
x + x + x + x /. x -> 3
```

The kernel first evaluates the left hand side expression to `4 x`, then applys the substitution. So my question occurs, is there a simple build-in mechanism that literally substitutes first, then does the possible further evaluation latter? If not, what is the easy and elegant way to do it by ourselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
Unevaluated[x + x + x + x] /. x -> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple possibilities:

```
Trace @ With[{x = 3}, x + x + x + x]
```

> {With[{x=3},x+x+x+x],3+3+3+3,12}

```
Trace @ ReleaseHold[Hold[x + x + x + x] /. x->3]
```

> {{{x->3,x->3},Hold[x+x+x+x]/. x->3,Hold[3+3+3+3]},ReleaseHold[Hold[3+3+3+3]],3+3+3+3,12}